# MySQL query to get, student report (grade, position) from Database

Tags: mysql, report

I am currently developing a school management application and require assistance with writing an SQL query to obtain a student report. Specifically, I need to retrieve the student's average score for the first and second sections of a specific session, class, and subject, which will be used to determine their position (1st), as well as their highest and lowest grades for that specific subject, session, and class.

I have two tables to work with: tbl_student_class, which stores the student's section, session, and class (st_cl_id, admission_number, session_id, section_id, class_id, date), and tbl_result, which stores the student's results (result_id, ca1, ca2, exam, section_id, session_id, class_id, subject_id).

Whenever a student's result is inserted into tbl_result for each section, it is stored for every session, subject, and class.

If a student does not have a record for the first or second section, the query should divide the sum of their third section and second or first section by 2 to obtain the cumulative, like so: (ca1 + ca2 + exam) for the first section score + (ca1 + ca2 + exam) for the second section score)/2. However, if the student has records for all three sections, the query should divide the sum of their first and second sections by 3 to obtain the cumulative. If the student only has a record for the third section, the query should not divide by any number to obtain the cumulative.

The cumulative value obtained is used to determine the student's position, as well as their highest and lowest scores for the subject, class, and academic session.

I can't upload image, I can paste the table here

Thank you for your assistance.

This is the query I have tried but is not working the way I expected it to

```
SELECT 
    s.name AS student_name, 
    s.admission_number,
    IFNULL((
        (SUM(CASE WHEN r.section_id = 1 THEN r.ca1 + r.ca2 + r.exam ELSE 0 END)
        + SUM(CASE WHEN r.section_id = 2 THEN r.ca1 + r.ca2 + r.exam ELSE 0 END)) / 2
    ), (
        (SUM(CASE WHEN r.section_id = 1 THEN r.ca1 + r.ca2 + r.exam ELSE 0 END)
        + SUM(CASE WHEN r.section_id = 2 THEN r.ca1 + r.ca2 + r.exam ELSE 0 END)) / 3
    )) AS cumulative_score
FROM tbl_result r
JOIN tbl_student_class sc ON r.session_id = sc.session_id 
    AND r.class_id = sc.class_id 
    AND r.section_id = sc.section_id 
    AND r.subject_id = <your_subject_id_here>
JOIN tbl_student s ON sc.admission_number = s.admission_number
WHERE r.session_id = <your_session_id_here> 
    AND r.class_id = <your_class_id_here>
GROUP BY sc.admission_number
ORDER BY cumulative_score DESC;
```

And this is what I am expecting, it a table but I can't upload images here:

```
SUBJECT CA1 CA2 EXAM    TOTAL   TERM_1  TERM_2  CUM.    GRADE   POSITION    OUT OF  HIGHEST SCORE   LOWEST SCORE    COMMENT
1   Agricultural Science    15  15  17  47  0   0   47  P   41st    49  87  35  Fair
2   Home Economics  15  14  20  49  0   0   49  P   44th    49  84  40  Fair
3   Social Studies  13  12  34  59  0   0   59  C   26th    47  86  37  Good
4   Business Studies    7   19  21  47  0   0   47  P   43rd    49  88  37  Fair
5   Civic Education 10  16  14  40  0   0   40  P   46th    48  79  37  Fair
6   Mathematics 8   15  29  52  0   0   52  C   36th    48  91  30  Good
7   Basic Science   13  10  28  51  0   0   51  C   28th    49  72  25  Good
8   English 7   16  31  54  0   0   54  C   24th    49  86  27  Good
9   Creative Art    11  10  18  39  0   0   39  F   47th    49  92  30  Failed
10  Yoruba  14  20  0   34  0   0   34  F   43rd    47  86  20  Failed
11  Basic Technology    15  14  31  60  0   0   60  B   23rd    47  78  39  V.
```

Comment: You're summing the same thing in both cases of `IFNULL()`. So if the first one is null, the second will be as well, and you'll divide `NULL / 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(r.section_ID)` to get the number of sections you have scores for. Then divide the sum of the scores by this to get the average. You don't need to use a conditional.

```
SUM(r.ca1 + r.ca2 + r.exam) / COUNT(r.section_ID) AS cumulative_score
```

Comment: Thanks sir, but it will not get the first section, second section and third section score, I want if section the given is 1 and or 2 it shouldn't apply that, however if the given section is 3 it should get the student score for that particular subject section, session and class... And also the position of the student

Comment: There's nothing in your query about a given section. Only the subject, session, and class are given.

Comment: Yes sir, how can I write the query please

Comment: You can add `AND r.section_id IN (<list of sections>)` to the `WHERE` conditions. It doesn't change the rest of the logic.

Comment: That get the student cumulative, but how can I get the student position, highest and lowest socre of that particular in that class sir?

Comment: Join with a subquery that gets the `MAX()` and `MIN()` grouped by class. And use the `RANK()` window function to get position.

Comment: But If I get for each student the rank will not work as expected or should I get all the student then from my PHP code I'd just get when the student_id is equal? And also I will be more great ful if you can write the query as another answer sir, I have gotten the idea but still confused

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions here. I answered the question you originally asked, I'm not going to handle additional problems.

Comment: thank you so much sir, it works with you answer... I am so much Greatful